# How do I get pfsense WAN IP after I set it up on DHCP?

Tags: ip, dhcp, vmware-workstation, freebsd, pfsense

I just installed a FreeBSD 64-bit virtual machine with pfSense 2.3.2 with VMware Workstation 12, but with VMware Workstation 11 hardware compatibility.

I booted and standard-installed pfSense and got to the menu, as suggested by many guidelines I found online. I proceeded with assigning the 2 interfaces I had, a WAN and a LAN, then setting up their IP addresses. The LAN I set staticly and had no problem with, but the WAN I set with DHCP.

After validation I noticed there is no apparent IP next to it. How do I get to display the DHCP attributed WAN IP so I can access the pfSense WebConfigurator Interface?

Screenshot of WAN and LAN IP addresses after setup:

[image]

Comment: `ifconfig em0`, inet6 and inet parts?

Comment: ifconfig em0? I don't understand

Comment: From a shell, you can use `ifconfig` to get the current configuration of the network interfaces. `ifconfig em0` shows only the configuration of the first Intel gigabyte network  adaptor. It will show many lines of output, the one with inet has the current IP v4 address and the one with inet6 has the current IP v6 address.

Comment: So you checked if VMware actually has a working DHCP server listening on the interface that pfsense connects to?

Comment: I did ifconfig em0 like you told me and this showed up, idk if DHCP server listenting on the interface, where in the output does it say so?
[output] (http://imgur.com/a/etfjK)

Comment: As the status reads `no carrier` are you sure it's connected? As you configured that WAN interface you should be aware what it is connected to and whenever there is a DHCP available on that  connection?

Answer (score 0):

You can define an IP WAN manually on the shell menu of pfSense for reach the (via Wan or / Lan) webConfigurator. If I remember correctly, you can reach WebConfigurator by the WAN and LAN for the first time.

After that you need to set it on the webConfigurator it's the easiest way to do that.

If you virtulize your configuration u need a bridge access on you're Virtual Machine, don't forget that. :p

Comment: you mean I should statically set my interfaces initially so I could access the web configurator then change interface settings?

Comment: Yes that's right.